# Ошибка в консоли js - скрипт работает

Tags: javascript

```
<script async>      

        function addCss(url) {      
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }       
            xhr.open("GET", url, false );
            xhr.send();
            var lazyStyle = document.createElement('style');
            lazyStyle.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            document.head.appendChild(lazyStyle);
        }
        addCss('data/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>');
        addCss('data/css/animate.min.css?v=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>');
        addCss('data/css/responsive.css?v=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>'); 
        addCss('data/css/style.css?v=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>');
    </script>
```

> (index):22 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
>   addCss @ (index):22

Как убрать данную ошибку из консоли?

Comment: Это не ошибка, а ворнинг.

Comment: @Igor в чём связь с дубликатом?

Comment: @andreymal В том, как пользоваться `XMLHttpRequest`-ом.

Comment: @Igor но автор данного вопроса не спрашивал об этом. Ещё раз, в чём связь?

Comment: @andreymal В том, как пользоваться `XMLHttpRequest`-ом.

Comment: @Igor но автор данного вопроса не спрашивал об этом. И ещё разок, в чём связь? (проголосовал за открытие)

Comment: @Igor да и на мете в комментарии ваш произвол упомянул, чо уж https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7307

Comment: Удивительно, но нормально оформленного вопроса про «Synchronous XMLHttpRequest» нету. А из этого можно сделать хороший вопрос для faq

Comment: Помогите убрать похожый ответ не помог..(((

Comment: @ИльяЦыпин зачем вам это убирать?

Comment: мешает мне... Хочу чтоб ни одной ошибки не было..

Comment: @ИльяЦыпин это не ошибка, это ворнинг. Зачем вам держать консула в абсолютной чистоте?

Comment: @ИльяЦыпин https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open - замените `false` на `true` и используйте ответ из дубликата

Comment: не понимаю как я плохо знаю язык

Comment: @Igor об этом нужно написать в ответе здесь, а не дубликатами размахивать налево и направо

Comment: если заменить скрипт не работает

Comment: @ИльяЦыпин а вы изучите язык в таком случае

Comment: ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Так и не смог сделать - помогите пожалуйста... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
xhr.open("GET", url, false ); // третий параметр async=false
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

> Note: Synchronous requests on the main thread can be easily disruptive
>   to the user experience and should be avoided; in fact, many browsers
>   have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely.
>   Synchronous requests are permitted in Workers.

То есть

> Синхронные запросы в основном потоке могут вызывать задержки в работе
>   браузера, и их следует избегать. Многие браузеры считают такой вид
>   запроса устаревшим. Синхронные запросы допустимы в фоновых Worker-ах.

```
function addCss(url) {      
  var xhr; // !!! используйте локальную переменную xhr
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url, true ); // или xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var lazyStyle = document.createElement('style');
    lazyStyle.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    document.head.appendChild(lazyStyle);
  }
  xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: Если так сделать скрипт перестаёт работать :(

Comment: Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: НЕ ПОМОГЛО(( Скопировал все правильно

Comment: используйте локальную переменную `xhr`